# Updating a text during a countdown in python stdout

Tags: python

I've done some research elsewhere and again nothing seems to work right. I've got the counter mostly working but when it goes from to 10 to 9 and below, it leaves a stray 0 behind so they appear as 90, 80, 70 etc.

I currently have:

```
stdout.write("\rRemaining: %r"%r)
stdout.flush()
```

Comment: we definitely need more info on what r is

Comment: Right now we only know that you want some kind of counter.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you overwrite the content of the line, and when you pass from 10 to 9 you have 1 character less. If you don't want to see the previous text you need to print a new line with the same (or greater) length of the previous one.

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
import time
from sys import stdout
n = 10
while n > 0:
    stdout.write('\rValue: %s' % str(n).rjust(2))
    stdout.flush()
    n -= 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Make the output a fixed length, <sup>so as to "replace" itself end to end</sup>

```
stdout.write( "\rRemaining: {0: 3d}".format( int( r ) ) )  # assumed 100..0
```